# Oracle UPDATE with JOIN 3 tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

```
UPDATE calculation  
LEFT JOIN transportorders ON calculation.ataid = transportorders.nr
LEFT JOIN partner ON partner.taid = transportorders.nr 
      AND calculation.FZZAEHLER=ATAFRACHTZAHLER.FZZAEHLER
SET calculation.BABRECHNUNGSINFO = '.....' 
WHERE calculation.ataid IN
(SELECT transportorders.nr 
 FROM transportorders 
 WHERE transportorders.tournr = '212041') 
AND partner.kundenid = '2486909';
```

I am trying this code, but it gives me an error that SET keyword is not found. Which means the joins are not as they should be. How do I make this selection in UPDATE? Regular SELECT works fine with the same tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `merge`:

```
MERGE INTO calculation c
     USING (SELECT '....' new_value, t.nr
              FROM transportoders t LEFT JOIN partner p ON p.taid = t.nr
             WHERE     t.tournr = '212041'
                   AND p.kundenid = '2486909') x
        ON (c.ataid = x.nr)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET c.babrechnungsinfo = x.new_value;
```

Comment: It selects nothing. 0 rows updated, when it should be 2. And I cannot understand why.

Comment: There was a typo in TOURNR value; how about now?

Comment: I found another solution. In the WHERE clause with IN. Anyway, I will test your solution as well later.

Comment: It merges all 6 rows instead of the 4 needed.